# user not seeing items, possibly security trimmed?

Tags: permissions, navigation

So I have a link in the quick launch that a user cannot see. I have triple checked the permissions and if I give her a direct link, she can access it, but the link doesn't appear for her. It's a custom .net app within an I frame to make it appear to be part of sharepoint.

It's based on an AD group only and other users, like myself, can see this link.
I have tried IE, Chrome and Firefox, all in private mode to prevent caching issues.
I even created a new link and explicitly added her, did a IIS-reset, cleared all her cookies and cache and still nothing. I have even rebooted the sharepoint app server.
It's possible there is a some subtle security issue I don't know about, but I have tried to rule that out.

I stopped inheritance to the page, removed all the groups and added the proper AD security group to the page and the user explicitly, both with full control.

I feel like one of the underlying services on the app server is not working but I don't know where to start troubleshooting that idea.
It's confusing for me, because if I make a change it instantly appears for me. I have logged in as this user on my computer and logged in as myself on her computer and the results don't change.
This user is working with the direct link for now, but I obviously don't understand something about sharepoint here and it's possible everything is working fine, I just don't get it....

Comment: When you log on with her account you can see the link?  So it is only present on her machine with her logon, not replicable in any other manner?

Comment: The link the the custom app works if she clicks on it via email, so she can access the page. But the link on the quick launch is not working.I think this is due to AD membership changes not updating in Sharepoint.

Comment: Have you tried removing her from the site collection and re-adding?  That's about the only thing I can think of.

Comment: I have not done that, I found a problem with the audience compalation, the AD group has 111 users and the sharepoint audience (it should be the same) shows 83, so I think this is the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked audience settings? Audiences are available on SharePoint server only and can also affect visibility of items especially in quicklaunch.

Try to place the link on other web's quicklaunch.

Check also the identity of user. There might be a problem while passing the identity of user form your .NET app to SP.